# Salesforce CLI: Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: Socket is closed

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I've recently installed salesforce CLI and VS Code on a Mac and for some reason deploying to my sandbox stop working after a few minutes of inactivity. The, I have to quit and execute VS code several times until it works again. This is the error I get:

```
5:57:55.557 Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: Socket is closed
```

The funny thing is my sandbox status in sfdx force:org:list appears as "Connected". sfdx force:auth:web:login works well too.

```
$ sfdx force:org:list
=== Orgs

     ALIAS       USERNAME                         ORG ID             CONNECTED STATUS 
 ─── ─────────── ──────────────────────────────── ────────────────── ──────────────── 
 (U) dev-xxx     xxx@xxx.com.xxx                  00D8E000000HtQ**** Connected
```

I've tried everything I have found on the internet but nothing seems to fix the problem permanently. For example, I have tried login out the org with:

```
sfdx force:auth:logout -u username@org.com.dev
```

And then authorizing again the org with my username and password, but still the same result: I can't deploy my source code to it although the org appears as "Connected" in the list of orgs.

This happens in all the sandboxes I use and only happens on my Mac, not on my Windows 10 computer. Why do I get this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: This error is different than the one that was flagged as a duplicate.